# CosmosDB Paging doesn't Return Correct Page Size

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Here's my data model from CosmosDB:

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "BookID": "100",
    "PublishDate": "2014-02-23",
    "Authors": [
        {
            "FirstName": "Jerry",
            "Title": "Writer"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Sally",
            "Title": "CEO"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Tom",
            "Title": "COO"
        }
    ] }
```

I know we can do paging on the `Book` object level. For example, I am able to do a query on `SELECT * FROM c` and set page number and page size.

However, am I able to do paging on the sub-object level? In this case, on the `Authors` level?

I am asking this question because I used the exact same code on both `Book` related query and `Authors` related query. `Book` query has the correct result in terms of the page number and page size. But `Authors` query always return all the items in the array. The query for `Authors` is:

> SELECT c.Authors FROM c WHERE c.BookID = "100"

The result is incorrect with the page size = 1, and page number = 1. It ends up returning all 3 of the authors.

So I was thinking maybe in Cosmosdb it used `Book` as an object, and paging only works on the `Book` level? That's why paging on the `Authors` level is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding around paging: Paging is related returning documents, not parts of a document.

If you ask for array elements, that's what you'll get. You'll get the full array, not a subset. Now, if you have, say, 100 documents, each with the same `BookID=100`, then paging will affect how many of those 100 documents are returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to query the Authors in this case, you could do the following:

```
SELECT c.BookID, a.FirstName, a.Title FROM c JOIN a IN c.Authors
```

This is detailed here in the CosmosDB docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join